# Postgresql COPY command issue

Tags: postgresql

```
copy (select * from TABLE_NAME) TO '/home/name/teste.csv';
```

This is the command line, it seems pretty simple I've read the documentation on this link (https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/sql-copy.html), checked my postgresql version and when I run the code it gives me this error

```
ERROR:  could not open file "/home/name/teste.csv" for writing: No such file or directory

********** Error **********

ERROR: could not open file "/home/name/teste.csv" for writing: No such file or directory
SQL state: 58P01
```

The file is there, checked with 'pwd' the path an everything seems ok, also tried the code with "WITH CSV" in the end and nothing.
Anyone seeing something I'm not?

Comment: The path needs to exist on the **server** and the OS user that runs the server needs to have the privileges to write there

Comment: It does, the csv files has the privileges and postgresql also (pgadmin in my case)

Comment: pgAdmin runs on the _client_, not on the server. So giving "pgAdmin" privileges (whatever that is supposed to mean) is not enough.

Answer (score 1):

For this command to work, there needs to be `/home/name` on the database server, and the operating system user `postgres` must have write access to that directory.

Answer (score 0):

The file `teste.csv` needs to be placed in the directory `home/name/` in the **database server**, not in the client. The database user also needs to have the necessary permissions to access the file.

An option to do that without moving the file into the database server is to use the `stdin` of [`psql`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/app-psql.html) from your client console:

```
$ cat teste.csv | psql yourdb -c "COPY tabela_teste FROM STDIN;"
```

abs!